# Is there any concern in Setting "maxBufferSize" to 1GB of WCF NetTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, memory-management, buffer, nettcpbinding, transport

I have a Duplex communication which sends `Small` as well as `Large` messages.

In very rare cases I have more data to be send, because of this reason I am in a confusion to change the `TransportMode` to `Streamed`.

So I set the buffer size to `1GB` (or a Large Size).

```
maxBufferSize="1073741824"
```

Is this cause my `Small` message communication ?

Answer (score 1):

As the setting says this is the *maximum* buffer size not the buffer size used for all requests. Although maxBufferSize is only used for defining the buffer size for headers when the message is streamed